Navigating directly to Angular routes with path parameters
Is it possible navigate directly to Angular routes with path parameters through the browser?
I want to access my chart component directly from the browser using link like this "http://localhost:8080/dmport/chart/787698cb". When i tried to do that i get 404 error
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Message The requested resource [/dmport/chart/787698cb] is not available


ie: In my app-routing.module.ts, I have routes like below:
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'chart/:uid', component: ChartComponent },
{ path: 'accomodation', component: AccomodationComponent },
{ path: 'offers', component: OffersComponent }

Yes it is possible, but you need to configure your web server accordingly.
